# No output on binary tree traversal in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, data-structures, binary-tree

I am a rookie programmer and I have a project which implies using binary trees. All I have to do is to insert a node, delete a node and add two methods of tree traversal. The issue is I can't get my code to work. I decided to add few helper functions such as check_element and create_NewNode to help me out implement easier. I don't get an output on my console after running or it simply greets me with a runtime error. I have got a header file, IO.c file to store my functions and the main.c.to test header file Implemented functions.

```
Here is IO.c , used to store the functions.



 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "Library.h"

    struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;

    };

    struct node *root;


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        //function to determine if an element is already in the tree
    void check_element( struct node *node, int value)
    {
        while( node != NULL ){
            //checking if the value is here
            if( value == node->data ){
                printf("The element %d already exists in the tree!",value);
                exit(0);
            //if the value is smaller, go left
            }else if( value < node->data ){
                check_element( node->left, value );
            //else go right
            }else if( value > node->data ){
                check_element( node->right, value );
            //else the element was not found and we can add it to th tree
            }else{
                printf("Adding the element %d to the tree.",value);
                exit(0);
            }

        }//end while

    }//end check_element



    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


        //helper function to crate a new node and set left and right pointers to NULL
    struct node *create_NewNode(  int value )
    {
        struct node *ptr;
        struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        if( ptr == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation error!");
            exit(-1);
        }

        //assigning the data to the newly created node
        temp->data = value;

        //setting left and right pointers to NULL
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;

        return temp;
    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


        //function to add a new value to the tree;
    struct node *insert_value( struct node *node, int new_value )
    {

        //checking if the element already exists to the tree
        check_element( node, new_value );

        //checking if the tree is empty
        if( node == NULL ){
            node = create_NewNode( new_value );
        //if the value is smaller, we add it to the left
        }else if( new_value < node->data ){
            insert_value( node->left, new_value );
        //else we add it to the right
        }else{
             insert_value( node->right, new_value );
        }

        return node;

    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    void printPostorder( struct node *node )
    {
         if (node == NULL){
                printf("The tree is empty!");
                exit(0);
         }else{
                //first go left
                printPostorder( node->left );

                //then go right
                printPostorder( node->right );

                //finally, print the node value
                printf("%d", node->data);

         }
    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    void inorder_traversal( struct node *node )
    {
       if( node == NULL) {
            printf("The tree is empty!");
            exit(0);
       }else{
            //first go left
            inorder_traversal( node->left );

            //print the node value
            printf("%d ",node->data);

            //then go right
            inorder_traversal( node->right );

       }
    }


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/




This is the header file, called Library.h



 //prototype for NewNode
struct node *create_NewNode( int value );
    //prototype for insert_value
struct node *insert_value( struct node *node, int new_value );
    //prototype for printPostordre
void printPostorder( struct node* node);
    //prototype for printInorder
void inorder_traversal( struct node *node );
    //prototype for check_element
void check_element( struct node *node, int value);



And, finally, the main.c: `enter code here:



 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "Library.h"

    int main()
    {
        // TEST CODE

        struct node *root;
        root = NULL;

        insert_value(root, 1);
        insert_value(root, 2);
        insert_value(root, 3);


         printPostorder( root );
        inorder_traversal( root );







        return 0;
    }


PS: I did my best to write this code, but, as I said, I am a rookie and I'm pretty bad at coding.I'd also like to appologize for any grammar mistakes, i am not an englishman.
```

Comment: You should become very close friends with the debugger. Step through your program line by line. (It's small enough that this is feasible.) Verify that everything is the way you expect it after each line. Indeed, the very first thing you do is call `insert_node` and you might notice something when you step through it and then try to insert the second node.

Comment: your function `void check_element( struct node *node, int value)` always calls `exit()` (maybe after a few recusive calls) Modify it to **return** a value that is useful to the caller, maybe an int, maybe a pointer or a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this post. I have got it to work. This is what I used:

**For the header file:**

```
///\file Header.h
///\brief The header containing all the prototypes for our functions.
struct node *Create_node( int value );
void delete_value(struct node **root, int val_del) ;
void inorder_traversal( struct node *node );
void insert_value( struct node **head,  int new_value );
void pre_order_traversal( struct node* node );
struct node* search_by_value(struct node* node, int value);
int random_value_generator(int domain);
```

**For the implementation of the functions:**

```
    ///\file Functions.c
///\brief C library implementation for BST.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Header.h"

//In this structure we'll be storing our BST.
struct node{
    ///\struct struct node
    ///\brief It represents our structure to store our BST.

    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;

};





/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*
        Helper function which creates a new node, containing the desired value and setting left and right
        pointers to NULL.
    */
struct node *Create_node( int value )
{
    ///\fn struct node *Create_node(int value)
    ///\brief Returns a new node, initialised with "value" and 2 NULL pointers, left and right.
    ///\param value The value which we want to initiliase the newly created node with.
        //Creating the new Node and allocating memory to it.
    struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        //Assigning the desired value to the newly created node.
    new_node->data = value;
        //Setting left and right pointers to NULL;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    return new_node;
};


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



    /*
        The first traversal method.
    */


void pre_order_traversal( struct node* node )
{
    ///\fn pre_order_traversal(struct node* node)
    ///\brief A function used to 'traverse' the tree. It actually is a printing function.
    ///\param node It represents the starting point of printing.
        //Checking if the tree is not empty.
   if( node != NULL ) {
    ///It will print the root, then the left child, then the right child.
        //Printing the node.
      printf( "%d ",node->data );
        //Printing the left child.
      pre_order_traversal( node->left );
        //Printing the right child.
      pre_order_traversal( node->right );
   }
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /*
        A function which inserts a new node in the tree.
    */
void insert_value( struct node **head,  int new_value )
{
    ///\fn  insert_value(struct node **head,  int new_value)
    ///\brief Inserts a new node into our BST.
    ///\param head This parameter is passed as a double pointer to avoid any conflicts with other fucntions.
    /// and represents the starting point of insertion. The function will start searching for the appropriate
    /// position to insert the value.
    ///\param new_value Is the new value which will be assigned to the new node;

        //Initialising the pointer.
    struct node *current = *head;
        //Checking if the the current node is NULL, if it is, we create a new node.
    if( current == NULL){
        //If the root is NULL, then we create a new new node, containing the new value.
        current = Create_node( new_value );
        *head = current;
    }else{
        //Else, if the value is smaller, recur to the left.
        if( new_value < current->data ){
            insert_value( &current->left, new_value );
        }else{
            //Else recur to the right.
            insert_value( &current->right, new_value );
        }

    }
}



/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*
        The second traversal method.
    */

void inorder_traversal( struct node *node )
{
    ///\fn inorder_traversal(struct node* node)
    ///\brief A function used to 'traverse' the tree. It actually is the second printing function.
    ///\param node It represents the starting point of printing.
   if( node != NULL ) {
        ///It will print the left child, then the root, then the right child.
        //Printing the left child.
      inorder_traversal( node->left );
        //Printing the root.
      printf( "%d ",node->data );
        //Printing the right child.
      inorder_traversal( node->right );
   }
}




/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /*
        A function which deletes a node.
    */
void delete_value(struct node **root, int val_del)
{
    ///\fn void delete_value(struct node **root, int val_del)
    ///\brief It is the most complex function and it is used to delete a node.
    /// There are multiple cases of deletion, such as: a leaf node (a node without any children),
    /// a node with a child on the right, a node with a child on the left or a node with 2 children.

    //We are starting from root, with two pointers: current and parent.
    struct node *current = *root;
    struct node *parent;

    //We recur on the tree untill we find the node containing the value which we want to remove.
    while (current->data != val_del) {
        //Moving the parent to root. The root's parent is NULL. (root has no parent)
        parent = current;
            //If the value is greater the parent's value, recur right.
        if (current->data > val_del) {
            current = current->left;
        }else{
            //Else recur left.
            current = current->right;
        }
    }

    //Checking if the node is a leaf node. (no children on the left or right)
    if ((current->left == NULL) && (current->right == NULL)) {
            //Comparing the node's value with the value of its parent.
            //If the value is smaller, we remove the left children.
        if (current->data < parent->data) {
            parent->left = NULL;
        }else{
            //Else we remove the right child.
            parent->right = NULL;
        }
        free(current);
    //Else, we check if it has a child on the left.
    }else if (current->right == NULL) {
                //Checking if our node is the root.
            if(current == *root) {
                //Using an aux to free the root, so the memory is not allocated to it anymore .
                struct node *aux;
                aux = (*root)->left;
                free(*root);
                (*root) = aux;
                //If the node is not the root, we proceed.
            }else{
                    //If the node's parent value is greater the the value of our node. If true, we replace
                    //the parent's left child with its left succesor and remove (free) the node.
                if (current->data < parent->data) {
                    parent->left = current->left;
                    free(current);
                }else{
                    //Else, we do the same thing, but for the parent's right child.
                    parent->right = current->left;
                    free(current);
                }
            }
     //Else, we check if it has a child on the right.
    }else if(current->left == NULL) {
                //Checking if our node is the root.
            if(current == *root) {
                //Using an aux to free the root, so the memory is not allocated to it anymore.
                struct node *aux;
                aux = (*root)->right;
                free(*root);
                *root = aux;
                //If the node is not the root, we proceed.
            }else {
                if (current->data < parent->data){
                        //If the node's parent value is smaller the the value of our node. If true, we replace
                        //the parent's left child with its right succesor and remove (free) the node.
                        //It is the mirrored code of the previous case.
                        parent->left = current->right;
                        free(current);
                }else{
                        //Else, we do the same thing, but for the parent's right child.
                        parent->right = current->right;
                        free(current);
                }
            }
    //Else, the node has 2 children. This is the last case.
    }else if( (current->right != NULL) && (current->left != NULL)){
            //In order to replace the root, we need to go one step to the right,
            //and then all the way to the left, retrieve the smallest value,
            //which will replace the root.
            struct node *temp = current->right;
            int aux;
            while (temp->left != NULL) {
                    temp = temp->left;
            }
            //This si where we do the swap.
            aux = temp->data;
            current->data = aux;
            temp = temp->right;
    }
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /*
        Helper function to determine if a value already exists in the tree.
    */
struct node* search_by_value(struct node* node, int value)
{
    ///\fn struct node* search_by_value(struct node* node, int value)
    ///\brief It is a function used to check if an element already exists in the tree.
    /// If the fucntion returns NULL, it means that the element DOESN'T belong to the tree.

        //Checking if the current node is empty or it has the value which we are looking for.
    if (node == NULL || node->data == value){
             return node;
             free(node);
    }

        //If the value is greater, recur right.
    if( value > node->data ){
            return search_by_value(node->right, value);
    }else{
                //Else recur left.
            return search_by_value(node->left, value);
    }
    //Returning NULL if the element wasn't found.
    return NULL;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*
    A simple function to generate random numbers,
    between 0 and a domain.
    */
int random_value_generator(int domain)
{
    ///\fn int random_value_generator(int domain)
    ///\brief It generates random numbers between 0 and a set domain.
    ///\param domain It represents the dmain.(the upper boundry for our generation)
    return rand()%domain;
}
```

**And finally the the main file:**

```
///\file main.c
///\brief The driver program for our BST library, containing a command line.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Header.h"

//Setting the root to NULL.(empty tree)
struct node *root=NULL;

int main()
{
    //Preparing the command line. The choice is like a task selector.
    int choice;

    //Infinitely recuring until the user decides to exit or there is an error.
    do{
        //Printing the command line and acquiring the choice.
        printf("\nWhat would you like to do ? Select:");
        printf("\n1-Add value;\n2-Delete value;\n3-Print In-Order;\n4-Print Pre-Order;\n5-Random;\n6-Exit;");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nYour choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice){

            //The first case is used for insertion of a new value.
            case 1:{
                //Initialising the local values.
                int iterations=0,number=0,value=0,iterator=0;
                //Setting up a pointer, for later use.
                struct node *ptr;
                //Acquiring the number of iterations.
                printf("\nHow many values would you like to insert? Type a value:");
                scanf("%d",&iterations);

                //Inserting values as many times as we initiliased "iterations".
                while( number < iterations ){
                    printf("\nValue[%d]=",iterator);
                    scanf("%d",&value);

                    //Using the pointer to check if the value already exists.
                    ptr = search_by_value( root, value );

                    if( ptr == NULL ){
                            //In case of ptr = NULL, we add it to the BST.
                            insert_value(&root,value);
                            value = 0;
                    }else{
                        //Else we ask for another value, without affectig the number of iterations.
                        printf("\nThe element %d already exists in the tree!",value);
                        //Resetting the pointer and the vaue to be reused.
                        value = 0;
                        ptr = NULL;
                        //A simple way to keep the loop consistent.
                        //If we want to insert 10 values and 1 would already exists,
                        //we would only have 9 values. This way, even if there a values
                        //already exists, we will still have to insert the appropriate
                        //nuber of values.
                        number--;
                        iterator--;
                    }
                    //Incrementing the iterators to prevent an ifinite loop.
                    number++;
                    iterator++;
                }
                //Reseting the iterator to be used later.
                iterator=0;
                break;
            };//end case-1

            //The second case is used for deletion.
            case 2:{
                //Initialising the value.
                int d_value=0;
                //Acquiering the value we want to delete.
                printf("\nWhich value would you like to delete? \nType a value:");
                scanf("%d",&d_value);

                //Checking if the value exists in the tree.
                struct node *ptr = search_by_value( root, d_value );

                if( ptr != NULL ){
                    //If ptr != NULL, it means that the value exists in the tree
                    // and it can be deleted.
                    printf("\nDeleting %d !",d_value);
                    //Deleting the value.
                    delete_value(&root, d_value);
                    //Reseting the value for laer use
                    d_value = 0;
                }else if( ptr == NULL ){
                    //Else the value does not belong to the tree, so it cannot be deleted.
                    printf("\nThe element %d doesn't belong to the tree!",d_value);
                    printf("\n");
                    //Resetting the pointer and the value for later use.
                    d_value = 0;
                    ptr = NULL;

                }else{
                    //Else our tree is empty.
                    printf("\nEmpty Tree!");
                }
                break;
            };//end case-2

            //The third case is used for in-order traversal.
            case 3:{
                printf("\nIn-order traversal:");
                inorder_traversal(root);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            };//end case-3

            //The fourth case is used for pre-order traversal.
            case 4:{
                printf("\nPre-order traversal:");
                pre_order_traversal(root);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            };//end case-4

            //The fifth case is used for randomly inserting value into teh BST.
            case 5:{
                //Initialising the values.
                int iterations=0,number=0,value=0,iterator=0,domain=0;
                //Setting up a pointer for later use.
                struct node *ptr;
                //Acquiering the number of iterations.
                printf("\nHow many values would you like to insert? Type a value:");
                scanf("%d",&iterations);

                //Acquiering the domain for the random generator.
                printf("\nPlease type the domain for the randomly generated numbers.");
                printf("\nPlease type a value:");
                scanf("%d",&domain);

                //Iterating until all the values have been successfully inserted.
                while( number < iterations ){
                    //The new value to be inserted is generated using our fucntion.
                    value = random_value_generator(domain);

                    //Checking if the values already exists in the tree.
                    ptr = search_by_value( root, value );

                    if( ptr == NULL ){
                            printf("\nInserting %d!",value);
                            //If ptr = NULL, we can safely insert the value into our BST.
                            insert_value(&root,value);
                            //Resetting the value for later use.
                            value = 0;
                    }else{
                        //Else, we cannot insert the value, as it already exists.
                        printf("\nThe element %d already exists in the tree!",value);
                        //Resetting the pointer and the value.
                        value = 0;
                        ptr = NULL;
                        //Same trick to insert the exact number of values.
                        number--;
                        iterator--;
                    }
                    //Incrementing to prevent infinite looping.
                    number++;
                    iterator++;
                }
                //Resetting the iterator for later use.
                iterator=0;
                break;

            };//end case-5

            //The sixth case is used to exit the proram at will.
            case 6:{
                exit(0);
            };//end case-6

            //The default case occurs in case of error. (hope not)
            default :{
                 printf("\nError!");
                 exit(-1);
            };//end default

        }//end switch

    }while(1);//end while

    return 0;
}
```

I used double pointers and that got rid of my problems. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more mistakes, but I read the `create_node()` and want to advice on it:

```
struct node *create_NewNode(  int value )
{
    struct node *ptr;
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if( ptr == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //assigning the data to the newly created node
    temp->data = value;

    //setting left and right pointers to NULL
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

Here you are creating two nodes, while you intend to create only one. You treat `temp` as the new one, while you forget about `ptr`. You don't need to create another node!

What you need is the pointer of the tree, so that you add the newly constructed node at that tree (thus you could pass another parameter to that function, tree's pointer).

BTW, I removed the casts of malloc, as explained in [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

---

I suggest trying to fix your code after my advice. However, I will link you to [treemanagement.c](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1498-2/), which is [c](/questions/tagged/c) code for a tree, fully commented, and it's the way I learned about this data structure, it might can in handy in the future!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try it out.